# How do I do a Django authorization data check?

Tags: python, django

So, I wrote the code for the reg.html page. If the registration data is filled in correctly, the form is saved and the account is created. I checked everything, the data is entered into the database. The only thing left to do is to make authorization. But here's the question - how do you do a check for the correct data? To put it simply, if the user logs in and such an account actually exists, then it should be redirected to the main page. Otherwise, the site will display "There is no such account". Here is the code below.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .form import SignUpForm, RegisterForm
from .models import Registration

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html',)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'main/about.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            return redirect('log')
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'main/reg.html', {
        'form': form
    })

def log(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            if Registration().objects.filter().exists():
                return HttpResponse('Да')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Нет')
                
    form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'main/log.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Registration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Никнейм', max_length = 18)
    mail = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Введите email', max_length = 30)
    password = models.CharField(verbose_name='Введите пароль', max_length = 18)
    
class SignUp(models.Model):
    mail = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Введите email', max_length = 30)
    password = models.CharField(verbose_name='Введите пароль', max_length = 18)
```

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/main/reg.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-log">
        <div id="inside">
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="forgot" id="home">На главную</a>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user" id="user"></i>
            <h2 id="create">Войти в аккаунт</h2>
            <div id="block"></div>
                <form method="post">  
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="brands">
                        <a href="#" class="brand"><i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="brand"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="brand"><i class="fa-brands fa-vk"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="brand"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="or">или</p>
                    {{ form.mail }}
                    {{ form.password }}
                    <button id="signup" type="submit">Войти</button>
                </form>
                <a href="#" class="forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
                <div class="border"></div>
                <p class="or">Нет аккаунта?</p>
                <a href="{% url 'reg' %}" class="forgot">Создать</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aef78a2820.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about),
    path('register', views.register, name='reg'),
    path('login', views.log, name='log'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the `authorization` check in Django, you will need to `authenticate` the user using the credentials provided in the login form.

Django provides a built-in `authentication` system, which simplifies this process.
What I can see, in your current implementation, you are using a custom model Registration for user data, which might not be integrated with Django's authentication system.

In most of the cases, you should be using Django's User model for handling user accounts. This model is designed to work seamlessly with Django's default `authentication` framework. If your Registration model is a replacement for the User model, it's crucial to ensure it's properly set up for authentication, which can be actually a complex task (***I assume you are not doing this***).

You can try this in your views.py file by modifying log method you already defined.

`views.py`:

```
#Import Django Authentication Functions: Import Django's authenticate and login functions.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import SignUpForm

def log(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home') #make sure to change this as per your need
            else:
                return HttpResponse('No such account')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'main/log.html', {'form': form})
```

*****Make sure you adjust the function as per your need.***

I would recommend you to check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for better understanding

Comment: hey man, i have created account in data base, but even if i enter correct information it returns 'no such account'. In models.py i have 'username, mail, password' for registration and 'mail, password' for login. Maybe i should change smth?

Comment: To help you more on this. please provide your models.py and some more details like your urls.py and HTML form template that is using for login.

Comment: Okay, I have done.

Comment: I can see you created a custom model name Registration and SignUp. Is there any reason why you didn't use Django default users model?

Comment: I didn't know about it xD and I don't now how to make custom CSS view using Django users model